# Sharepoint 2010 change database server IP

Tags: sharepoint

The ip address of our sharepoint 2010 database server has changed, so how do we make changes so that it points to new ip?

Comment: should you change the dns entry? is this related with sharepoint?

Comment: I could change dns entry if sharepoint was configured with hostname, but in my case its ip address

Comment: Maybe this will help http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93d99015-4f8e-490f-801f-f76fe8243154/sharepoint-configuration-database-ip-address-change-cannot-connect-to-configuration-database?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Answer (score 1):

I am Not sure

But you can try this stps :

- You can run the SharePoint Configuration Wizards on the Sharepoint sever,
- Dissconnect from the current farm,
- Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizards again,
- Choose to Connect to the current Farm
- Write your DB server name, and choose your configuration DB
- Finish the Wizard

Also ,

If the IP addresses have changed at the server, check that the HOST A entries in DNS relevant to the server have also been changed to reflect the new IP of the server

Refernece : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93d99015-4f8e-490f-801f-f76fe8243154/sharepoint-configuration-database-ip-address-change-cannot-connect-to-configuration-database?forum=sharepointadminlegacy